# How to set mandatory field validation on Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid to store the User's academic detail. On clicking an "Add" link, user will be provided with grid popup ,which accepts the input. Now I have a requirement to make it as a mandatory field.

How can I set and raise validation message if User tries to submit the form without entering any academic data?

Comment: Hello, did you try add validation into model fields like [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/eBOQa)?

Comment: @Ademar , the validation rule you mentioned is for making sure that user does not submit blank value when they edits .. right ? For my requirement e.g : I have a grid in my form, which is used to take the education detail of user. When a form is generated, it is an empty grid. Requirement is to make sure that user enters at least one education detail to the grid before submitting the form.